microtype and \RaggedRight creating friction and hard to deal with overfulls
I previously asked why exactly \RaggedRight was causing overfull and underfull issues, and this was answered almost unanimously with a "microtype is usually the first option`". I want to stick to utilizing the microtype package as I was told in person by a friend who is as expereinced as I am that even with RaggedRight text, it should be used. I personally have only used it in justified text, but I believe him and took a jab at making a template using it.
When I got answers, they were greatly written and were very encouraging to me, a novice. Though I tried to "simply" use microtype and I still got overfull. One answer even still had an overfull error (I am not the type to be picky about how things are done, but... i feel like my question was quite specific and the naswer could have been reviewed before posting).
So here is my attempt at utilizing a suggested answer
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    letterpaper
]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[
    american
]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\fixpar}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \rightskip=\glueexpr\RaggedRightRightskip+0pt plus #1em\relax
  \par
  \endgroup
}

 
%%% Final Settings
\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 2.0em} % 2.0em is default
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{01.6in}
\RaggedRight
 
\begin{document}
 
\section{Introduction}

The Embargo Act of 1807 was a significant mistake in early American history. President Thomas Jefferson's attempt to use economic pressure instead of military \linebreak action backfired, damaging the American economy without achieving its foreign policy goals. This essay will explore why the Embargo Act was implemented, its negative consequences, and how it might have been better managed. The Act was the most controversial and important law passed during Jefferson's presidency. However, it led to what \textit{Teaching American History} describes as \enquote{widespread smuggling}, showing its ineffectiveness. \fixpar{1.6}

\section{Background and Implementation}

In 1807, the United States was caught between warring European powers. Jefferson sought a peaceful way to protect American ships from British and French interference. \textit{The Encyclopedia Britannica} states that \enquote{Jefferson and Secretary of State James Madison determined to enforce a recognition of American rights by commercial retaliation, a concept rooted in American foreign policy since the Nonimportation Agreements that preceded the American Revolution}. Said determination \linebreak from both parties led to the Embargo Act, and this later Jefferson to tell Congress on December 18, 1807: \enquote{The communications now made, showing the great and increasing dangers with which our vessels, our seamen and merchandise are threat\linebreak ened, on the high seas and elsewhere, from the belligerent powers of Europe, and it\linebreak being of the greatest importance to keep in safety these essential resources, I deem it my duty to recommend the subject [embargo] to the consideration of Congress, who will doubtless perceive all the advantage which may be expected from an inhibition of the departure of our vessels from the ports of the United States}. The Act completely stopped American ships from leaving U.S. ports for any foreign destination\linebreak, showing how far-reaching the Embargo Act was. \fixpar{1.6}

\section{Consequences of the Embargo}

The Embargo Act had severe effects on the American people and economy. According to \textit{The Encyclopedia Britannica}, \enquote{The Act was a hardship on U.S. farmers as well as on New England and New York mercantile and maritime interests, especially after being bolstered by harsh enforcement measures adopted in 1808}. It was also very difficult to enforce. Jefferson's April 1808 statement revealed the problems: \enquote{Whereas information has been received that sundry persons are combined or combining \& confederating together on Lake Champlain \& the country thereto adjacent for the purposes of forming insurrections against the authority of the laws of the U.S. for opposing the same \& obstructing their execution, and that such combinations are too powerful to be suppressed by the ordinary course of judicial proceedings, or by the powers vested in the marshals by the laws of the U.S.}. This resistance showed how unpopular and ineffective the Act was, with many people trying to break the rules.

\section{Reasons for Failure}

The Embargo Act failed because it hurt Americans more than the countries it was meant to punish, and it was almost impossible to enforce. \textit{Teaching American History} notes that \enquote{the Embargo Act proved ineffective, crippling the American economy but having minimal impact abroad}. Additionally, \textit{The Encyclopedia Britannica} states that \enquote{its effects in Europe were not what Jefferson had hoped. French and British dealers in U.S. cotton, for example, were able to raise prices at will while the stock already on hand lasted; the Embargo Act would have had to endure until these inventories were exhausted}, which made the Act less effective. These factors combined make the Act fail to achieve its intended goals. 

\section{Prevention and Alternative Solutions}

The Embargo Act's failure could have been avoided with more targeted measures. Instead of stopping all trade, Jefferson could have limited only some trade. The Act shows that a more careful approach definitely could have been more effective. Jefferson could have also tried harder to negotiate directly with Britain and France, maybe using the threat of some trade restrictions, to achieve U.S. goals without stopping all trade. Additionally, the Act's implementation required \enquote{no vessels of any description whatever, and wherever bound, whose employment is confined to the navigation of bays, sounds, rivers, and lakes, within the jurisdiction\linebreak of the United States... shall be allowed to depart from any port of the United States without having previously obtained a clearance}. This strict rule made it difficult to comply. \fixpar{1.6}

\section{Conclusion}

The Embargo Act of 1807 provides an important lesson in American history. Jefferson's well-intentioned attempt to use economic pressure instead of military action backfired badly, severely damaging the American economy without achieving its foreign policy goals. This failure demonstrates the importance of carefully considering all potential consequences when using economic policies in foreign relations. As the United States navigates complex international relationships today, leaders must carefully weigh how their foreign policy decisions might affect people at home. Analyzing the Act reveals that the Embargo Act required \enquote{the master or commander shall have delivered to the collector or surveyor of the port of departure, a manifest of the whole cargo on board}, which shows to what extent measures were\linebreak taken to enforce it. \fixpar{1.6}

\end{document}

It is quite time consuming to check which fixpar value (never got it to work) and to put linebreaks for it all not to work. I want to be able to understand the way professionals solve these problems, but it seems so dificult. Are these issues not able to be automatically taken care of by either microtype or ragged2e? I would greatly appreciate a response and explanation as to how to fix what I am going thorugh

why are you using \linebreak ?????????

it's almost never a good idea to use \linebreak and makes no sense really in a ragged setting. but forcing breaks before a comma, or mid-word with no hyphen just ensures the output is unreadable. microtype can help in most cases but it can't correct input that is explicitly forcing bad breaks

The problems with the bad linebreaking in this example can not be fixed with microtype or any package as they are forced linebreaks within the source, using \linebreak (rather than \\ ) so making linebreaking more difficult and being placed in unfortunate places (mid-line, mid-word with no hyphen, before a comma, ...)
Removing the \linebreak and \fixpar and the ragged setting the whole text justifies with no warnings.

If you want to allow some raggedness at the right rather than stretching inter-word space so much you can set \rightskip eg
\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 2em}

Adding additional stretch glue to every line is rather unlikely to make tex create any additional over or under full boxes as all the break points used in the justified text are still available, with some others becoming available due to the additional flexibility.

\documentclass[
    12pt,
    letterpaper
]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[
    american
]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\fixpar}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \rightskip=\glueexpr\RaggedRightRightskip+0pt plus #1em\relax
  \par
  \endgroup
}

 
%%% Final Settings
\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 2.0em} % 2.0em is default
%\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{01.6in}% surely not??
%\RaggedRight

\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 2em}

\begin{document}
 
\section{Introduction}

The Embargo Act of 1807 was a significant mistake in early American history. President Thomas Jefferson's attempt to use economic pressure instead of military  action backfired, damaging the American economy without achieving its foreign policy goals. This essay will explore why the Embargo Act was implemented, its negative consequences, and how it might have been better managed. The Act was the most controversial and important law passed during Jefferson's presidency. However, it led to what \textit{Teaching American History} describes as \enquote{widespread smuggling}, showing its ineffectiveness.

\section{Background and Implementation}

In 1807, the United States was caught between warring European powers. Jefferson sought a peaceful way to protect American ships from British and French interference. \textit{The Encyclopedia Britannica} states that \enquote{Jefferson and Secretary of State James Madison determined to enforce a recognition of American rights by commercial retaliation, a concept rooted in American foreign policy since the Nonimportation Agreements that preceded the American Revolution}. Said determination  from both parties led to the Embargo Act, and this later Jefferson to tell Congress on December 18, 1807: \enquote{The communications now made, showing the great and increasing dangers with which our vessels, our seamen and merchandise are threatened, on the high seas and elsewhere, from the belligerent powers of Europe, and it being of the greatest importance to keep in safety these essential resources, I deem it my duty to recommend the subject [embargo] to the consideration of Congress, who will doubtless perceive all the advantage which may be expected from an inhibition of the departure of our vessels from the ports of the United States}. The Act completely stopped American ships from leaving U.S. ports for any foreign destination, showing how far-reaching the Embargo Act was.

\section{Consequences of the Embargo}

The Embargo Act had severe effects on the American people and economy. According to \textit{The Encyclopedia Britannica}, \enquote{The Act was a hardship on U.S. farmers as well as on New England and New York mercantile and maritime interests, especially after being bolstered by harsh enforcement measures adopted in 1808}. It was also very difficult to enforce. Jefferson's April 1808 statement revealed the problems: \enquote{Whereas information has been received that sundry persons are combined or combining \& confederating together on Lake Champlain \& the country thereto adjacent for the purposes of forming insurrections against the authority of the laws of the U.S. for opposing the same \& obstructing their execution, and that such combinations are too powerful to be suppressed by the ordinary course of judicial proceedings, or by the powers vested in the marshals by the laws of the U.S.}. This resistance showed how unpopular and ineffective the Act was, with many people trying to break the rules.

\section{Reasons for Failure}

The Embargo Act failed because it hurt Americans more than the countries it was meant to punish, and it was almost impossible to enforce. \textit{Teaching American History} notes that \enquote{the Embargo Act proved ineffective, crippling the American economy but having minimal impact abroad}. Additionally, \textit{The Encyclopedia Britannica} states that \enquote{its effects in Europe were not what Jefferson had hoped. French and British dealers in U.S. cotton, for example, were able to raise prices at will while the stock already on hand lasted; the Embargo Act would have had to endure until these inventories were exhausted}, which made the Act less effective. These factors combined make the Act fail to achieve its intended goals. 

\section{Prevention and Alternative Solutions}

The Embargo Act's failure could have been avoided with more targeted measures. Instead of stopping all trade, Jefferson could have limited only some trade. The Act shows that a more careful approach definitely could have been more effective. Jefferson could have also tried harder to negotiate directly with Britain and France, maybe using the threat of some trade restrictions, to achieve U.S. goals without stopping all trade. Additionally, the Act's implementation required \enquote{no vessels of any description whatever, and wherever bound, whose employment is confined to the navigation of bays, sounds, rivers, and lakes, within the jurisdiction of the United States... shall be allowed to depart from any port of the United States without having previously obtained a clearance}. This strict rule made it difficult to comply.

\section{Conclusion}

The Embargo Act of 1807 provides an important lesson in American history. Jefferson's well-intentioned attempt to use economic pressure instead of military action backfired badly, severely damaging the American economy without achieving its foreign policy goals. This failure demonstrates the importance of carefully considering all potential consequences when using economic policies in foreign relations. As the United States navigates complex international relationships today, leaders must carefully weigh how their foreign policy decisions might affect people at home. Analyzing the Act reveals that the Embargo Act required \enquote{the master or commander shall have delivered to the collector or surveyor of the port of departure, a manifest of the whole cargo on board}, which shows to what extent measures were taken to enforce it.

\end{document}


You remarked,

One answer even still had an overfull error.

First off, please distinguish between error messages and warning messages. There's a meaningful difference between these message types. And, overfull-box messages are of the warning type, not the error type.
I must confess to not understanding the purpose of the \linebreak and \parfill instructions, unless they're meant to be the equivalent of demonstrating that if huge boulders and massive logs are placed on a road, it gets a lot more difficult to get to one's destination if the road in question is the only way to go.
I compiled the test document under MacTeX2024 and pdfLaTeX without the \linebreak and \parfill directives. If \RaggedRight is in effect but  microtype isn't loaded, I get no overfull-box warning messages at all. If I then recompile the test document with microtype (and \RaggedRight still in effect), I get exactly three instances of overfull boxes. The lines in question are:



The associated warning messages are:
Overfull \hbox (0.1695pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--29
Overfull \hbox (0.19525pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 44--45
Overfull \hbox (0.21942pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 48--49

Let's round up the largest of the three lengths to 0.22pt. With 1in=72.27pt and 1in=25.4mm, 0.22pt translates to 0.00304in or 0.077mm -- which I'll round up to 0.08mm.
If protrusions into the right-hand margin of the text block that range from 0.06mm to 0.08mm manage to bend you out of shape -- congratulations, your visual acuity puts that of a healthy adult eagle to shame. Not that I'm claiming that eagles are known to stare at typeset text for any length of time...
Seriously: The entire purpose of TeX and friends is to provide high quality solutions to a wide range of typesetting needs. To obtain these solutions, in all but the most trivial cases TeX and friends have to perform optimizations over a surprisingly large number of constraints. If it so happens that one of these constraints -- say, "don't let the width of a line exceed \linewidth" -- is violated occasionally, but by no more than 0.08mm at a time, that's definitely not an error in anyone's book.
Let's go back to the premise of the query:

I was told in person by a friend who is as expereinced as I am that even with RaggedRight text, [the microtype package] should be used.

In view of the previously mentioned fact that your test document does not produce any overfull boxes if \RaggedRight is in effect but microtype is not loaded, you may want to inform your friend that, alas, microtype isn't a panacea. It can even cause overfull lines to be produced! Yikes! Happily, though, as long as no (typographic) slugs are placed at the ends of the lines in question, no one will ever know...

so perhaps is this something that I should message the developers of the micro type package about? It's a small issue, but perhaps this can be solved with a showcasing of my example and perhaps they or ragged2e devs can help iron out this issue. Not op by the way

@FelixMaldonado - It could indeed be productive to ask the author/maintainer of the microtype package why a \RaggedRight document that produces no overfull boxes starts producing a few of them once microtype gets loaded.
